# Setting up a Ruby on Rails Server

Tags: software-development, web-server, server, ruby

I am thinking of buying a raspberry pi, because I want to host a personal website. I am using a UK Internet provider (Virgin Media), and I want to use my internet connection to allow access to my website!

I have found quite a few resources for setting up a LAMP server, with pi, but I am a Ruby on Rails Developer.

Anyone can provide some help please?

Comment: Setting up Ruby on Rails on a Raspberry Pi should be no different than setting it up on any Debian based Linux.

Answer (score 13):

This is a nice guide on exactly how to [setup Ruby on Rails.](http://elinux.org/RPi_Ruby_on_Rails) Obviously using the RPI.

I think it would be pointless to copy and paste the whole article here, so here is a google cached version of the above page as well. [Google Cache Ruby on Rails](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:25APqLHoLHIJ:elinux.org/RPi_Ruby_on_Rails+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=za)

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest looking at [this distribution](http://sirlagz.net/2013/02/14/raspbian-server-edition-version-2-3/) which has a number of things stripped out that makes it a bit better suited to running a server. SSH is already running in it, so you can just SSH (pi/raspberry) in.

Remember to 
    sudo raspi-config

once you've got it installed on a card and running, and use the menu option for expanding out the root-fs to fill your card.

You may need to

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To get a list of latest packages and

```
apt-cache search curl
```

(curl or whatever package it doesn't find) before you

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Then [the guide to setup Ruby on Rails](http://elinux.org/RPi_Ruby_on_Rails) should get you the rest of the way. I've done it successfully twice now, and it's pretty simple to google any errors you get and find the command you need to run to get over the hurdles.

But remember that it's going to take HOURS to install, and there's no messages for long stretches of time, so be patient.